# MSSQL Transpose / Pivot data in to columns by type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in mssql i want to transpose in to columns, its a list of image names with an image type.

[image]

But i want it formatted like this

[image]

So its pivoted by column, then if there is multiples in one cell, sepperated by Commas, how am i best doing this??

this is the current query

```
select code,img_type,fileName 
from images join 
     Intranet.dbo.image_lkup lk 
     on lk.img_id = images.[type]
```

This is MSSQL 2012

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? Could you please convert the images to text? It makes it better readable. See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a limited file type, then i would use conditional aggregation :

```
select code, 
       max(case when img_type = 'Cutout' then fileName end) as Cutout,
       max(case when img_type = 'Dims' then fileName end) as Dims,
       max(case when img_type = 'Ins' then fileName end) as Ins
from images im inner join 
     Intranet.dbo.image_lkup lk 
     on lk.img_id = images.[type]
group by code;
```

Comment: This is nearly there.... i just dont know what to do if there is multiple images, this only returns one..any idea?

Comment: @Fabio. . . If you have a multiple images, then how would you represent it ?

Comment: Just sepperated by Commas

ABC.JPG, BCD.JPG, EEE.JPG in each column